# Separable extensions and Hensel's Lemma

Tags: field-theory

I know that in a characteristic $0$ field, every irreducible polynomial is separable. This follows directly from the equivalence:

$$f \:\text{ separable} \iff \gcd(f,f') = 1$$

Now I'm reading Neukirch's Algebraic Number Theory and on page 143 (Henselian Fields) he says:
Let $(K,v)$ be a nonarchimedean valued field, ($\hat K$, $\hat v$) its completion, ($K_v$,$v_v$) its separable closure in $\hat K$. When $K_v$ is algebraically closed in $\hat K$ then $\operatorname{char}(K)=0$ and Hensel's lemma holds in $\mathcal{O}_v$ (the valuation ring of $K_v$).

For me, it seems like he says that if every irreducible polynomial is separable, then $\operatorname{char}(K) = 0$ because the above means: Let $f$ be an irreducible polynomial with coefficients in $K$, then if $K_v$ is algebraically closed $f$ splits into linear factors over $K_v$ and since $K_v$ is a separable extension of $K$, $f$ is separable.

But is this true? And why does Hensel's lemma hold in $\mathcal{O}_v$?

Comment: He is not saying that $K_v$ should be algebraically closed, but algebraically closed in $\hat{K}$.

Comment: @CaptainLama Thanks for your answer. Why does this imply that char(K) = 0?

Comment: @M.Wang It does not imply $char(K) = 0$, this is a mistake in the book. The sentence should read "hence in particular WHEN $char(K)=0$", as it does in the german version.